# Read a Text asset(text file from assets folder) as a String in Kotlin (Android)

Tags: android, string, file, kotlin, android-assets

I need to read a text file stored at `src/main/assets/` i.e; in the assets folder and get it as a string.

Is there a simple way to do it.

Java copy, paste, convert functions are giving trouble, so I'd rather use a kotlin way.

I need a kotlin way to do this

Answer (score 89, accepted):

I found this in a youtube video. Here is the link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o5pDghyRHmI

```
val file_name = "qjsonfile.json"
val json_string = application.assets.open(file_name).bufferedReader().use{
            it.readText()
        }
```

Saves the JSON or text to the string `json_string`.

Comment: Please can u tell us how to wrtie on it

Comment: I tried this and it said "Unresolved reference: application"  Not sure where I should be getting "application" from.

Comment: @DINATAKLIT 

you can't write to file's located on asset folder. They are read only

Comment: OP you should update that application is actually the context object. Thanks works well.

Comment: How to address the file in the project?

Answer (score 10):

You don’t need `Application` to read a text file in the `assets` folder.

```
fun readAsset(context: Context, fileName: String): String =
    context
        .assets
        .open(fileName)
        .bufferedReader()
        .use(BufferedReader::readText)
```

Answer (score 7):

When in doubt close the stream yourself!

```
application.assets.open(file_name).apply {
                json_string = this.readBytes().toString(Charsets.UTF_8)
            }.close()
```

Comment: no need to `.close()` if you add the `. bufferedReader().use{...}`