# Android Kotlin | Picking random line from text file

Tags: android, kotlin, file

very simple, android kotlin.
i have a file in the project assest folder with sentence in each line.
what i wants, is when i open dialog, it will select random line and put it as the dialog message.
i couldn't find any proper solution.
dialog's code:

```
class JokeFragment : DialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        return activity?.let {
            val sentence: String = //random line from the file
            // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
            val builder = Builder(it)
            builder.setMessage(sentence)
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel){ _, _->}
            // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
            builder.create()
        } ?: throw IllegalStateException("Activity cannot be null")
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason you cannot make a String Array resource with your string lines? Then you can pull a random string from the array. If you put it in a text file, you will have to do file IO which would involve having to do load the file in a background thread first and then updating the dialog back on the main thread after the file is loaded. String resources are preloaded at app startup, so you don't have to worry about using background threads to retrieve them.

Comment: I see no file. I dont see you opening a file. I dont see you reading a file. You did not enough.

Comment: sure, i know how read to entire file, but at line 5 I asked for help

Comment: `which would involve having to do load the file in a background thread first`? @Tenfour04. Not needed at all. Maybe if the file has megabyte size. Further typing all data in a string array is terrible work. No a file is perfect and flexible.

Comment: For line 5 stop at .readLine() for the fifth time. How many lines in the file?

Comment: i meant the line 5 of the code above

Comment: Yes i saw that. But i see no file. I see no... Well i already told you.

Comment: the file in in the internal storage assets folder

Comment: @blackapps, I’m assuming a megabyte or more size since it looks like a joke of the day sort of app so it should have hundreds of lines. Reading such a file would add a little bit of jank to the UI thread. Typing out a string array resource would be terrible, but of course you would write a script to create it for you.

Comment: If it is the assets folder then you should have told that of course on the first line of your post.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62878278/17787605) answer:

```
fun readRandomLineFromAsset(context: Context, fileName: String): String =
        context
            .assets
            .open(fileName)
            .bufferedReader()
            .use(BufferedReader::readText)
            .lines()
            .shuffled()
            .first()
```

Updated code - shuffled().first() instead of random()

Random picks same line every time fo some reason.

Comment: It shows nothing? Or same line every time?

Comment: What do the logs show? What kind of error?

Comment: Where this 'jokes.txt' file is physically located? Is it in `app/src/main/assets/` folder?

Comment: Try to rebuild app.

Comment: The last thing I can advise is to clean the application data from the emulator, then delete the application itself and try again.