How to read google-services.json file from android project in Kotlin/java
I want to read the file during runtime in Kotlin function, the file I want to read is stored
at projectname/app/credentials.json and I want to read credentials.json.
similar case can be how firebase read its credential file google-services.json
PS: I don't want to put file in assets as I have already figured assets method

facing the same issue

What exactly have you tried that doesn't work the way you expect?

I have tried to import Gradle plugin in Kotlin but was not able to. even after trying different dependency used in play service sdk. @AlexMamo

I think you can't access such a file during runtime. You might access it during build time, as google-services.json. For usage during runtime consider assets folder

@Christopher how to access it like google-services.json at build time?

The file google-services.json is not directly readable from within the application.
Firebase is able to access the values in the file because of the google services gradle plugin.  That plugin reads the file at build time, and injects the values it finds into your app using resources at runtime.  From the linked documentation:

The google-services plugin has two main functions:

Process the google-services.json file and produce Android resources that can be used in your application's code.


If you want to read the file on your own, you will need to do something similar - write a gradle plugin that finds the file, then adds it to your app in a way that's readable, such as resources or assets.  It can't be read otherwise.

You can find your answers through this link
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62878278/21735165
You have to put the file into your assets folder and read it. Check out the link

I don't want to put the my file in asset. I want to read from app level projectname/app/ folder

Then i don't see how to help you.



You Should use the Context openFileInput method that this method can get the file of app path. 

val file:FileInputStream = context.openFileInput("credentials.json")




In Kotlin, you can read a file from the filesystem using standard Java I/O operations. Here is a way you can read the "credentials.json" file located in your project directory:
Run this code :
import java.io.File

fun readCredentials(): String? {
    val filePath = "app/credentials.json" 
    val file = File(filePath)
    return if (file.exists()) {
        file.readText()
    } else {
        null
    }
}

fun main() {
    val credentials = readCredentials()
    println(credentials)
}

Adjust the filePath variable to the correct relative path based on your project structure. This code will read the contents of "credentials.json" and return it as a string and if the file doesn't exist, it will return null values.
